# Python - controller method - how to find which one

Tags: python, controller, view

I have a sample Python project, the default of the website to be opened in this form:
https://mycompany.com/counterbooth/enter?_next=/

I can locate the controller "counterbooth",
ie. controller\default.py
def conunterbooth();

but I don't know what method I should look into for "enter?_next" ?
Also I don't know which "view" (html) I should look into?